# Selectively replacing columns in R with their delta values

Tags: r, diff

I've got data being read into a data frame R, by column.  Some of the columns will increase in value; for those columns only, I want to replace each value (n) with its difference from the previous value in that column.  For example, looking at an individual column, I want

```
c(1,2,5,7,8)
```

to be replaced by

```
c(1,3,2,1)
```

which are the differences between successive elements

However, it's getting really late in the day, and I think my brain has just stopped working.  Here's my code at present

```
col1 <- c(1,2,3,4,NA,2,3,1) # This column rises and falls, so we want to ignore it
col2 <- c(1,2,3,5,NA,5,6,7) # Note: this column always rises in value, so we want to replace it with deltas
col3 <- c(5,4,6,7,NA,9,3,5) # This column rises and falls, so we want to ignore it
d <- cbind(col1, col2, col3)
d
fix_data <- function(data) {
    # Iterate through each column...
    for (column in data[,1:dim(data)[2]]) {
        lastvalue <- 0
        # Now walk through each value in the column, 
        # checking to see if the column consistently rises in value
        for (value in column) {
            if (is.na(value) == FALSE) { # Need to ignore NAs
                if (value >= lastvalue) {
                    alwaysIncrementing <- TRUE
                } else {
                    alwaysIncrementing <- FALSE
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if (alwaysIncrementing) {
            print(paste("Column", column, "always increments"))
        }

        # If a column is always incrementing, alwaysIncrementing will now be TRUE
        # In this case, I want to replace each element in the column with the delta between successive
        # elements.  The size of the column shrinks by 1 in doing this, so just prepend a copy of
        # the 1st element to the start of the list to ensure the column length remains the same
        if (alwaysIncrementing) {
            print(paste("This is an incrementing column:", colnames(column)))
            column <- c(column[1], diff(column, lag=1))
        }
    }
    data
}

fix_data(d)
d
```

If you copy/paste this code into RGui, you'll see that it doesn't do anything to the supplied data frame.

Besides losing my mind, what am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't assign lastvalue anywhere...

Answer (score 3):

Without addressing the code in any detail, you're assigning values to `column`, which is a local variable within the loop (i.e. there is no relationship between `column` and `data` in that context).  You need to assign those values to the appropriate value in `data`.

Also, `data` will be local to your function, so you need to assign that back to `data` after running the function.

Incidentally, you can use `diff` to see if any value is incrementing rather than looping over every value:

```
idx <- apply(d, 2, function(x) !any(diff(x[!is.na(x)]) < 0))
d[,idx] <- blah
```

Answer (score 2):

`diff` calculates the difference between consecutive values in a vector.  You can apply it to each column in a dataframe using, e.g.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,5,7,8), y = (1:5)^2)
as.data.frame(lapply(dfr, diff))

  x y
1 1 3
2 3 5
3 2 7
4 1 9
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed a few more things.  You are using a matrix, not a data frame (as you stated in the question).  For your matrix 'd', you can use

```
d_diff <- apply(d, 2, diff)
#Find columns that are (strictly) increasing
incr <- apply(d_diff, 2, function(x) all(x > 0, na.rm=TRUE))
#Replace values in the approriate columns
d[2:nrow(d),incr] <- d_diff[,incr]
```